# How to show long alt text when it exceeds the width or height of container

Tags: html, html-email

In the article, https://litmus.com/community/learning/12-alt-text-in-html-email
It mentioned about:

> In many email clients, ALT text will disappear once the size or length of the text exceeds the width and/or height of the image container. Due to this behavior, it’s probably best to stick to shorter descriptions and smaller font sizes to avoid having your ALT text removed altogether.

But our PM really want to show the alt text...Is there any ways to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to convince your PM to use short ALT tags. Rather then risking them not to show up.

If he doesn't take the advice as PM's tend to do, there's another option. Style your ALT tags, for example use a small yet readable font-size to make the text fit. Don't forget to set line-height, as many email clients will cut off the bottoms of letters if the line height is shorter than the font-size. Maybe this [blog](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/mastering-alt-text-in-email) will help you out too!

```
<img src=".../image.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Get 30% off today!" style="font-size: 18px;line-height:20px;" />
```